# Как взять значение из поля объекта одной модели и создать на их основе объект другой модели

Tags: python, django

Разработка на Django4.
Кратко:
Загружаю на сервер файлы docx (модель "Документ"). Отображаю их список на сайте. Сделал кнопку для запуска функции по обработке содержимого файла. Выбираю из содержимого файла всё нужное и сохраняю в поле этого самого типа "Документ" ( в поле модели `file_extracted_data = models.JSONField(        blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Данные извлеченные из файла")`.

Перебор и вывод данных из этого поля на странице осуществить не сложно, а вот как сделать заполнение формы данными из этого самого поля?

Например, файл обработал и сохранил в поле следующее:

```
"client_dict": {"client_1_data": {"client_lastname": "Белоусова", "client_firstname": "Валерия", "client_patronym": "Александровна"}
```

В детальную вьюху Документа захожу и вижу эти данные. Рядом кнопка "Создать Контакт". Жму на неё и отображает форму создания нового Контакта (ModelForm) с уже заполненными полями "Белоусова Валерия Александровна".

В настоящий момент никак не могу сообразить как передать в форму эти самые данные. Открывается лишь пустая форма.

Ткните пожалуйста, куда копать.

Comment: Начните копать с документации. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial02/